# How storage gets updated after migration

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a list of comments, where each comment is as `Message` component.

A message has an "edit" button, and on click on this button, it's text is replaced by form, which is not connected to ApolloClient.

`Message` component is also just for displaying data, it's not connected to ApolloClient.

The code is following:

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';
import { number } from 'prop-types';
import withCurrentUser from '!/lib/hoc/withCurrentUser';
import Message from '!/components/messages/Message';


class CompanyComments extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    companyId: number.isRequired
  };

  updateComment = (content, contentHTML, id) => {
    const {doEditCommentMutation, companyId} = this.props;

    return doEditCommentMutation({
      variables: {
        id: id,
        content: content
      }
    });
  }


  render(){
    const { data: {loading, comments}, companyId } = this.props;

    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            !loading &&
            comments &&
            comments.map((comment, i)=>(
              <Message
                key={i}
                index={i}
                id={comment.id}
                content={comment.content}
                user={comment.user}
                onReply={this.handleReply}
                handleUpdate={(content, contentHTML)=>(
                  this.updateComment(content, contentHTML, comment.id)
                )} />
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const getCommentsQuery = gql`query
  getComments(
    $commentableId: Int,
    $commentable: String
  ) {
    comments(
      commentableId: $commentableId,
      commentable: $commentable,
      order: "createdAt ASC"
    ) {
      id
      content
      user {
        id
        nickname
      }
      createdAt
    }
  }
`;

const editCommentMutation = gql`mutation
  editCommentMutation(
    $id: Int!,
    $content: String!
  ) {
    editComment(
      id: $id,
      content: $content
    ) {
      id
      content
      createdAt
      user {
        id
        nickname
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default compose(
  graphql(getCommentsQuery, {
    options: ({companyId}) => ({
      variables: {
        commentableId: companyId,
        commentable: 'company'
      },
      pollInterval: 5000
    })
  }),
  graphql(editCommentMutation, {name: 'doEditCommentMutation'})
)(CompanyComments);
```

The only component, that is connected to ApolloClient – is this component with code above.

**Interesting behavior** begins, when `editComment` mutation is performed and the list of components, received by `getComments` query is getting magically updated.

How? I'm not using optimistic response or `refetch`.

Is it new behavior of ApolloClient storage, that is used instead of Redux, figuring out changes in fetched data automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing a `pollInterval: 5000` in

```
graphql(
  getCommentsQuery, 
  { 
    options : { ... }  // << here
  }
)
```

`pollInterval` forces the query to be fetched repeatedly. In your example, every 5 seconds. Know more [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#refetching)

Since Apollo cache stores the data normalized, any items with the same `__typename` and `id` will just be updated in the store and it's UI representation automatically updated for components that are listening to any query that returns them. More about [automatic cache updates](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#automatic-updates).

Comment: Thank You! Automatic cache update is my case, very good feature!

Comment: Yes, saves a lot of time! One of the great advantages of apollo client. And we can also leverage it for local state management via `apollo-link-state`